# nginx issue with redirecting styles

Tags: nginx, redirection

I want to configure my home network to do everything through my raspberry pi.

My router is 192.168.1.1, and the pi is 192.168.1.2. They are static IPs.

I have nginx running on the pi, and I'm using dynamic DNS to the router to access from outside. I then have requests to the router forwarded to the pi.
In other words, when I type in my dynamic DNS address, I'm directly on the pi's IP, which is being served by nginx.

I then have my nginx config redirecting URLs, such as `/router` and `/media` to other devices around my house, which are also on static IPs.

The problem I have is that, for example, on `/router` there are files and folders that also need to be redirected, eg `/images/*.gif` and `/styes/*.css`, and also some `*.js` and `.gif` files in the root `/` folder, some of which are referenced from the files in `/style`.

So my question is, how do I redirect EVERYTHING that is under `192.168.1.2/router` to `192.168.1.1`, including rewriting URLS?

See below what I've tried so far. At the moment, this does not work and I either get a `502` relating to circular redirects.

Thanks

```
location /router/ {
    sub_filter_once off;
    sub_filter_types text/html;
    sub_filter "http://192.168.1.1" "http://192.168.1.2";

    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;

    # First try serve as file, then dir, then throw a 404
    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /style {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/style;
}

location /image {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/image;
}

location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|js)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*) $1 last;
}
```